# I get multiple Ip with my ingress ressource and don't know why or how to fix it?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, nginx-ingress, strimzi

Hello guys I have an ingress controller running and i deployed an ingress for kafka (deployed through strimzi), but the ingress is showing me multiples Ip for the address, instead of one, so I'd like to know why and what can I do to fix it cuz from what I've seen in tutorials , whent you have an ingress the Ip given in the address is the same as th on in the ingress controller service ( in my case it should be : 172.24.20.195)  so here is the ingres controller components :

```
root@di-admin-general:/home/lda# kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx -o wide
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP               NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/default-http-backend-598b7d7dbd-ggghv   1/1     Running   2          6d3h   192.168.129.71   pr-k8s-fe-fastdata-worker-02   <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-controller-4rdxd          1/1     Running   2          6d3h   172.24.20.8      pr-k8s-fe-fastdata-worker-02   <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-controller-g6d2f          1/1     Running   2          6d3h   172.24.20.242    pr-k8s-fe-fastdata-worker-01   <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-controller-r995l          1/1     Running   2          6d3h   172.24.20.38     pr-k8s-fe-fastdata-worker-03   <none>           <none>

NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE    SELECTOR
service/default-http-backend       ClusterIP      192.168.42.107    <none>          80/TCP                       6d3h   app=default-http-backend
service/nginx-ingress-controller   LoadBalancer   192.168.113.157   172.24.20.195   80:32641/TCP,443:32434/TCP   163m   workloadID_nginx-ingress-controller=true

NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE    CONTAINERS                 IMAGES                                                   SELECTOR
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-controller   3         3         3       3            3           <none>          6d3h   nginx-ingress-controller   rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.35.0-rancher2   app=ingress-nginx

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE    CONTAINERS             IMAGES                                                         SELECTOR
deployment.apps/default-http-backend   1/1     1            1           6d3h   default-http-backend   rancher/nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend:1.5-rancher1   app=default-http-backend

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE    CONTAINERS             IMAGES                                                         SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/default-http-backend-598b7d7dbd   1         1         1       6d3h   default-http-backend   rancher/nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend:1.5-rancher1   app=default-http-backend,pod-template-hash=598b7d7dbd
root@di-admin-general:/home/lda#
```

and here are the kafka part:

```
root@di-admin-general:/home/lda# kubectl get ingress -n kafkanew -o wide
NAME                         CLASS    HOSTS                            ADDRESS                                  PORTS     AGE
kafka-ludo-kafka-0           <none>   broker-0.172.24.20.195.nip.io    172.24.20.242,172.24.20.38,172.24.20.8   80, 443   5d22h
kafka-ludo-kafka-1           <none>   broker-1.172.24.20.195.nip.io    172.24.20.242,172.24.20.38,172.24.20.8   80, 443   5d22h
kafka-ludo-kafka-2           <none>   broker-2.172.24.20.195.nip.io    172.24.20.242,172.24.20.38,172.24.20.8   80, 443   5d22h
kafka-ludo-kafka-bootstrap   <none>   bootstrap.172.24.20.195.nip.io   172.24.20.242,172.24.20.38,172.24.20.8   80, 443   5d22h
```

you see that we have 3 ips (172.24.20.242,172.24.20.38,172.24.20.8) instead of just one that from what I think should be 172.24.20.195, please if anyone can provide explanations, the link to the strimzi yaml used to expose an ingress is here : https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/06/12/accessing-apache-kafka-in-strimzi-part-5-ingress/
thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Your external IP is the one you see in `kubectl get svc`, in your case 172.24.20.195.

The other IPs you see in `kubectl get ingress` are ingress controller pod IPs, which are internal to your cluster.

Comment: yes your right but as for the ingress ressource the lsit of ip is only the one of the pods

Comment: Not sure what you mean... there's three IP addresses listed next to each ingress rule. That being said, I'm not sure why you need three ingress rules.